# Converting PDF to JPG of different sizes in PHP

Tags: php, pdf, jpeg, imagick

I want to convert PDF pages to JPEG, but I want each page to be converted to 3 images.

1. First one is high quality
2. Second is mid quality
3. Third is thumb images

I use this code but I did not know how to make it to 3 images:

```
$im = new Imagick();
$im->setResolution(100,100);
$im->readImage("files/xx.pdf");
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->writeImages("files/oman/oman.jpg",false);
```

This code will only convert each PDF page to one image.

Comment: When you say quality, what exactly do you mean?  JPEG quality, or a particular resize dimension?  Either way, you'll probably need to do three calls to `writeImages()`, changing the output as you require before each call.

Comment: i mean resize dimension. ok before the three calls of writeImages() what the command that do the resize

Comment: [`IMagick::resampleImage()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.resampleimage.php) can be used to resample to a new DPI.  Warning though, if you've got a lot of pages in that PDF, it will use *a lot* of memory.

Comment: yes i have a lot of pages on the PDF do you have another way to do this ?

Comment: $im = new Imagick();
    $im->setResolution(100,100);
    $im->readImage("files/Ajyal_11-10-12.pdf");
    $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
    $im->writeImages("files/oman/oman.jpg",false);
    $im->setImageResolution(100,200); 
    $im->resampleImage(100,200,imagick::FILTER_UNDEFINED,0); 
    $im->writeImages("files/oman/oman_2.jpg",false);
    $im->clear(); 
    $im->destroy(); does not work

Comment: Personally, because of memory issues, I would read in the PDF one page at a time, and write the images out manually, resizing as I went.

Comment: What do you want to reduce ?? Size or Resolution ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've created the first high res version of the page as a jpg, then just use php gd to resize it by reading in that generated jpg and resizing it down and exporting another jpg.  [This](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php) is the function you want and that page shows a simple example of how to resize images.

<strike>UPDATE: [This](http://www.sitepoint.com/image-resizing-php/) shows a pretty simple tutorial on how to resize with php</strike>

UPDATE: Sorry, look at the php.net link above, there are many many examples of how to resize an image, [here is a simple one](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php#98560).  All you need to do is take what is returned and use [imagepng()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php) to save the file locally.  (There are similar functions to save gif/jpg)

Comment: i thisnk this way will be better for me because i want to use 1000's of images i will gave it a try> thanks

Comment: in the tutorial it say "Actually, there is. Keep in mind that you aren’t changing the file’s original size. That same 200×400, 50 KB picture you uploaded only moments ago is still 200×400, 50 KB. This script only changes height and width attribute in HTML, so that your original picture conforms to the height and width you think will look best on your Web page." and i don't need this i want smaller image in size

Comment: Sorry, that was a bad example, I updated the answer again with a better explanation.

Comment: no problem thank you. but i was thinking what is batter to make 3 sizes of the image and save it on the server ?? or i can use php file that will return reduced size image every time it is requested without saving it ??? can you help with this pls

Comment: those are definitely two options.  The latter would be good if you want dynamic sizes and you may not know the sizes at this moment, the former is better for speed.  A better approach might be a hybrid, when a request comes for a file/size combo, find whatever naming convention you want for that, then check if the file exists, if so, just return that path to the browser, if not, generate it and save it so it doesn't have to be created next time.

Comment: If you know you'll have just the known set of sizes, just generate them all now in a loop and then you won't have to worry about it in the future.